# How to do replace particular part of string on every row of dataframe?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df with a filename column. The filename itself contains only piece of information that I need, which is an ID.

```
df:

filename
/path/to/file/in/folder 76317 1a2334bc-5d6e-7f89-123e-0f12fgf123.txt
```

I only need the part after folder and before the hash. So in this case 76317. All the files in the folder have the file folder path, space, ID i need, and space with the rest of the file name.

How do I remove everything from the file name column except the IDs I need on all rows for this particular column ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `str.extract` with a regex that looks for anything surrounded by 2 spaces:

```
>>> df
                                            filename
0  /path/to/file/in/folder 76317 1a2334bc-5d6e-7f...
1  /path/to/file/in/folder 76318 1a2334bc-5d6e-7f...

df['filename'] = df.filename.str.extract('\s(.*)\s', expand=False)

>>> df
  filename
0    76317
1    76318
```

Comment: this works as well. I will use this answer since it is more stable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your exact implementation, but have you tried using `str.split()`?

```
id = filename.split()[1]
```

Split each part of the filename by a space which you said occurs in every file, and get the middle item, which is index 1 in the list of sections returned by `split()`.

Comment: Under the assumption the spacing is as he suggested

Comment: amazing this works really nice. 

@RushabhMehta spacing is exactly the same. Thank you very much

Comment: @RustyShackleford All I'm saying is that sacul's answer is more stable

Comment: @RushabhMehta How so?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for fileName in column:
    ID = fileName.split(' ')[1]
```

You should try this approach *before* the strings are put into the dataframe, however, so you don't iterate over them twice.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the exact format, you can use `split` with panda's [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['filename'] = df['filename'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[1])
```